# SCSS - why does extended classes behave this way?

Tags: sass

I've got this SCSS code:

```
.a {
    color: red;
}

.b {
    @extend .a;
}

:not(.a) {
    color: green;
}
```

I'm expecting this:

```
:not(.a) {
  color: green; }
```

But I'm getting this:

```
:not(.a):not(.b) {
  color: green; }
```

Is there any document specifying that behaviour, or it's a compiler's bug?

Comment: Your compiler see's .a and .b as being exactly the same

Comment: @Brad normally compilers won't treat `A` and `B` variables as same after `A=B` assignment, so I expect this behaviour here too

Answer (score 3):

You are extending `.b`from `.a` and it gets a selector like `.a, .b`. When you are using a pseudoselector like `:not` it is using the selector generated.

In this case use a placeholder selector with `%`.

```
%redColor{
  color: red;
}
%greenColor{
  color: green;
}

.a {
    @extend %redColor;
    :not(&){
      @extend %greenColor;
    }
}

.b {
    @extend %redColor;
}
```

Output:

```
.a, .b {
  color: red;
}

:not(.a) {
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: Upwote for your workaround, but I'm still looking for any specifications describing this behaviour.

Comment: I edited it to make things clearer. Now `:not()`is inside the class. `:not()`is a pseudoselector like `:hover` and them are included when you extend a class. I understand your question though.